# How to edit index.html.erb file in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails will create several files for you, including app/views/home/index.html.erb. This is the template that will be used to display the results of the index action (method) in the home controller. Open this file in your text editor and edit it to contain a single line of code:

## Hello, Rails!

......and then i edit in notepad index.html.erb ,when i save this my notepad show the message this "check this fole is opened in another program".....a chech everywhere in computer no such is open

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why there is such an error. Maybe try to load all your ruby files in an IDE like NetBeans and try to change those files within a ruby project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the file opened in the browser? This could be causing the message..

But it's just a guess, I really have no idea.